# Composer pulling package from custom Git repository using tag or custom branch

Tags: git, composer-php

I am working on a PHP project that is using the Composer for dependencies management. For one of the packages, I am pulling from my own Github repository.

Following is the dummy configuration I am using in composer.json file

```
"require": {
    "my-package/my-custom-package": "dev-master"
},
 "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/my-package/smy-custom-package.git"
    }
],
```

As you can see, I am pulling from the master branch. How can I configure it to use a tag or another custom branch, instead?

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#vcs-tags-and-branches